# New Member entry in Civi

Tags: civimember, contacts, organization

What is the proper way to enter a new member (that is also a new company in the database).  I tried to do this via "memberships" "new member" and it did not seem correct and gave me an error message about missing a membership ID.  Is it necessary to add a new organization via "contact" first?

Comment: Welcome to SE! Just checking on terminology here ... Some organizations think of 'members' as being anyone on their mailing list or attending meetings etc but that usage does not need to involve CiviMember.  'Members' in Civi are (usually) time-limited and (often) paid - eg £10/year .  So, if you describe what membership means to you we can guide you better.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

It's a little hard to answer your question with just the info you gave and no screenshots, but I'll try my best.

When I go to **Memberships » New Membership**, this is the screen I see:
[image]

Note that the **Member** field allows me to either type in the name of an existing contact, or I can press **New Organization** (or Individual or Household) to create the contact on the fly.

To help us help you, it would be good to share the exact text of the error message and not a paraphrase.  Also, it's helpful to edit your original question so other folks see the whole issue at once.